# Как получить данные из input и перенести их в код Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

Мне нужно получить данные из поля `input` в HTML в код Flask для дальнейшей работы с ними. Я подключил модуль `request`, но получить данные все равно не удается. На странице ошибка `400 Bad Request`. Можно ли ее как-то решить?

HTML-код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/reg_style.css')}}" />
        <title>Регистрация</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Регистрация</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            <input class="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя">
            <input class="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш e-mail">
            <input class="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Придумайте пароль" type="password">
            <input class="pass_again" placeholder="Повторите пароль" type="password">
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/reg_run">
                <div class="button"><div class="text_button">Зарегистрироваться</div></div>
            </a>
        </form>
        <div class="log">Войти</div>
        <div class="restore">Восстановить пароль</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Flask-код:

```
@app.route('/reg', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def reg():
    return render_template("reg.html")


@app.route('/reg_run', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def reg_run():
    a = request.form['name']
    print(a)
    return a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скажите, пожалуйста, это вот так вы хотите отправить форму?

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/reg_run">
    <div class="button"><div class="text_button">Зарегистрироваться</div></div>
</a>
```

Подтяните, пожалуйста, основы HTML. Это просто ссылка, которая генерирует GET-запрос по указанному URL. Ну а результат предсказуемый, в обработчик не присылается вообще ничего, он падает с ошибкой и возвращает код 400.

Должно сработать вот так:

```
<form method="POST" action="/reg_run">
    <input class="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" />
    <input class="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш e-mail" />
    <input class="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Придумайте пароль" type="password" />
    <input class="pass_again" placeholder="Повторите пароль" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" />
</form>
```

В этом случае действительно будет отправляться POST-запрос с телом, в котором будут поля формы, которые потом можно будет получить и обработать.

И не забывайте закрывать тэги, косая черта обязательно нужна, даже если и без нее как бы работает.

Очень полезная ссылка:

- [Мега-Учебник Flask](https://habr.com/ru/post/346306/)